# Don't call function multiple times on chrome.storage.sync.onChanged

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've made a chrome extension that block urls, defined in the extension's options.

I use declarativeNetRequest rules to handle the block list.

to reload the rules I listen for changes in the chrome.storage.sync

this works fine, but if I change more than one setting that I listen for the function "updateblocklist" will be triggered once for each setting that has been changed.
This result in errors about the rule ids aren't unique since it's already taken, this is because the function will fire too quickly.

the updateblocklist remove all rules first and then add the blocked urls as rules.

background.js

```
chrome.storage.sync.onChanged.addListener(ps => {
    if (ps.list || ps.blocked || ps.homepage) {
        updateblocklist();
    }
});
```

So how can I still listen for multiple changes but only fire updateblocklist once?

I have the option of saving (clicking a button) or importing a json with the settings on my options page.

Importing json settings file:

```
chrome.storage.sync.clear(() => chrome.storage.sync.set(json, () => { location.reload();}))
```

Clicking save button:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({
'list': document.getElementById('list').value,
'blocked': document.getElementById('blocked').value,
'homepage': document.getElementById('homepage').value
});
```

Comment: Do you set the data in storage individually? If so, you can save all the keys in one call.

Comment: added info about saving the storage data

Comment: sorry wasn't maybe clear that this is two seperate options, either click button and save or import json file.

Comment: A single `set` will trigger a single `onChanged` event for any amount of keys. It means you call `set` more than once. Use devtools debugger to find the reason. For example maybe you attach a `change` listener on every element, in which case you should attach it just once to the container or to `document`. P.S. A workaround would be to use *debounce* in onChanged.

Comment: ah thanks I think I know why will see if I can change the way it saves if not I will try debounce. will a set trigger a single onChange even when you importing a json file?

Comment: ran with debounce, thanks man.